# How to flush the mails for a mailbox in exchange-2007

Tags: mailbox, exchange-2007

I am a Linux admin and I have to manage some Windows hosts too. I want to flush the mails for a particular mailbox in Exchange 2007. How I can do that ?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "flush the mails" - do you want to delete the whole mailbox of a user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean flush just like you would on postfix, then I know what you mean.  Open up Exchange Management Console on the machine and run this command:

```
get-queue –SortOrder:-MessageCount
```

You'll get a list of all the message queues that have undelivered mail, you can then:

```
retry-queue ID-OF-QUEUE
```

As far as flushing a particular mailbox of an actual user I don't think there's a way, but you can re-attempt delivery for specific delivery destinations with the above commands.  For more good information on dealing with Transport Queues in Exchange see: 
   http://www.exchangeninjas.com/troubleshootingexchange2007transportqueuingproblems